# Scrapy skip request based on previous crawl from same spider

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

In the below example, each bucket has lots of balls. There may or may not be a red ball in either bucket. To find out if a ball is red, we crawl it.

If a red ball is found I'd like to stop crawling the rest of the balls (i.e. I don't want a request sent out for the next ball, which I know it won't be red, because I've already found it).

Bucket and balls identifiers are query params for the base URL.

### What I've tried #1

*maintain a class state and check if a bucket already has red ball*

```
class BucketsBallsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test_spider'
    base_url = 'https://bucketswithballs.com'
    buckets = []
    balls = []
    buckets_with_red_balls = []
    
    def start_requests(self):
        for bucket in self.buckets:
            for ball in self.balls:
                if bucket in self.buckets_with_red_balls:
                    break
                url = add_or_replace_parameter(self.base_url, 'bucket', bucket)
                url = add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'ball', ball)
                yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
                
    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        is_red_ball = response.xpath('//*[@id="is_red_ball"]').extract()
        if is_red_ball:
            bucket_id = url_query_parameter(response.url, 'bucket')
            self.buckets_with_red_balls.append(bucket_id)
            yield {'bucket_with_red_ball': bucket_id}
```

### What I've tried #2

*yield requests in parse method*

```
class BucketsBallsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test_spider'
    base_url = 'https://bucketswithballs.com'
    buckets = []
    balls = []
    buckets_with_red_balls = []

    def start_requests(self):
        # Start from first bucket and first ball
        url = add_or_replace_parameter(self.base_url, 'bucket', self.buckets[0])
        url = add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'ball', self.balls[0])
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        is_red_ball = response.xpath('//*[@id="is_red_ball"]').extract()
        if is_red_ball:
            bucket_id = url_query_parameter(response.url, 'bucket')
            self.buckets_with_red_balls.append(bucket_id)
            yield {'bucket_with_red_ball': bucket_id}

        # Scrapy filter will skip duplicates
        for bucket in self.buckets:
            for ball in self.balls:
                if bucket in self.buckets_with_red_balls:
                    break
                url = add_or_replace_parameter(self.base_url, 'bucket', bucket)
                url = add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'ball', ball)
                yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)
```

For each example, Scrapy tells me in the console that it crawled every single URL. For performance reasons, I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work because Scrapy works in an asynchronous way, and I don't think you can stop the other requests as they may be already in course. You could raise a [CloseSpider()](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#closespider) exception to terminate the spider when a red ball is found, but concurrent requests would finish before the spider closes. See the Scrapy architecture [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html)

If you need it to stop and do not make **any** requests after a red ball is found, I think you want it to be synchronous. It would be probably easier to do with Python `requests` for example.

Having said that, I updated your example to work synchronously (I haven't tested). This will force Scrapy to make requests 1 by 1, regardless it's configured to make several concurrent requests, not very efficient though.

```
class BucketsBallsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'test_spider'
base_url = 'https://bucketswithballs.com'
buckets = []
balls = []

current_bucket_idx = 0
current_ball_idx = 0

def start_requests(self):
    # Start from first bucket and first ball
    url = add_or_replace_parameter(self.base_url, 'bucket', self.buckets[0])
    url = add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'ball', self.balls[0])
    yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
    is_red_ball = response.xpath('//*[@id="is_red_ball"]').extract()
    if is_red_ball:
        bucket_id = url_query_parameter(response.url, 'bucket')
        yield {'bucket_with_red_ball': bucket_id}
        return

    next_bucket, next_ball = self._get_next_bucket_and_ball()
    if not next_bucket:
        return      

    url = add_or_replace_parameter(self.base_url, 'bucket', next_bucket)
    url = add_or_replace_parameter(url, 'ball', next_ball)
    yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse)

def _get_next_bucket_and_ball(self):
    if self.current_ball_idx < len(self.balls) - 1:
        self.current_ball_idx += 1

    else:
        self.current_ball_idx = 0   
        if self.current_bucket_idx < len(self.buckets) - 1:
            self.current_bucket_idx += 1
        else:
            # No more buckets/balls to try
            return None, None

    next_bucket = self.buckets[self.current_bucket_idx]
    next_ball = self.balls[self.current_ball_idx]
    return next_bucket, next_ball
```